# Setting @ContextConfiguration during build

Tags: java, spring, ant

Is there a way to set the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation during an Ant build?

1) I have tried the replace task of ant which can modify the source during build. It works but is not a clean method.

2) I know I can also use the java properties file. That is, I can edit a `.properties` file during build and read it during runtime. But since the `@ContextConfiguration` is defined outside the class, I cannot access it.

Is there any elegant method to do this?

Comment: May I know why you want to set a Class @ContextConfiguration during build time?

Comment: @shazin because i want two separate targets with separate beans.

Comment: What you need is spring profiles